# what number should a shopping cart icon display

Tags: e-commerce, shopping-cart, counter

[image]

This icon shows how many items a user has added to the cart. In this case items A, B, C, E and F. Now let's imagine that the user adds two more units for item C.

So the updated cart is:

```
A - 1 unit
B - 1 unit
C - 3 units
D - 1 unit
E - 1 unit
```

What should that counter display? 5 (beacause of the different items) or 7 (because of the total number of units)?

Answer (score 2):

The number should show the total number of products contained in the purchase based on their individual price. This means all products with a single price, whether it's just an item or a pack.

In the example of the question, the three items C are not part of a pack, they have a unit price, so the total purchase number to show is seven. It would only be five if the three C items are part of a pack with a single total price.

You must think exactly the same as if it were a real purchase:

1. You buy two apples, a banana and a pear = 4 items
2. You add three more pears = 7 items
3. But then you discover there's a tray of four pears at a better price, you remove the individual pears and buy the pack. You have two apples, a banana, and a pack, regardless of its content = 4
   items

[image]